# Как автоматически установить высоту контейнера для SVG c viewbox?

Tags: css, svg

Если `SVG` не задавать жестких размеров, а задать соотношение сторон через `viewBox`, то SVG принимает ширину контейнера, а высота при этом определяется соотношением сторон. Даже если высота контейнера меньше высоты SVG.
Как сделать так, чтобы высота контейнера (`div#container`) автоматически определялась высотой SVG.
Попробовал `height: auto;`, но высота получается чуть больше, добавлял `padding:0; box-sizing:content-box;`, пробовал задать размеры SVG, но все равно снизу есть свободное пространство.

```css
   
#container {
    width: 180px;
    height: auto;
    background: yellow;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <svg fill="#000000" viewbox="2 2 20 20">
        <path d="M 11 2 L 11 11 L 2 11 L 2 13 L 11 13 L 11 22 L 13 22 L 13 13 L 22 13 L 22 11 L 13 11 L 13 2 Z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Пока единственный способ (до которого я дошел) не повторять размеры иконки - использовать `css-variables` как для ширины, так и для высоты:

```css
:root {
    --icon-size: 180px;
}

#container {
    width: var(--icon-size);
    height: var(--icon-size);
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <svg fill="#000000" viewbox="2 2 20 20">
        <path d="M 11 2 L 11 11 L 2 11 L 2 13 L 11 13 L 11 22 L 13 22 L 13 13 L 22 13 L 22 11 L 13 11 L 13 2 Z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Это вроде снимает лишние зависимости в коде (можно одной переменной редактировать сразу оба параметра), но ведь иконка может быть и не квадратной. **Можно ли автоматически выставить высоту контейнера `SVG` с использованием `viewBox`?**

Comment: У меня всё нормально при `#container { display:flex }`, либо `#container {
    display:inline-flex }`

Comment: Также помогает `#container { line-height:0 }`

Comment: Да, действительно. Могут ли быть побочные эффекты с flex и inline-flex? Вроде с другими элементами они ведут себя также как block и inline-block. Хорошие варианты, спасибо. Ответ?

Comment: Да, вы правы, для соседних элементов это равнозначно block и inline-block.

Comment: В общем случае, это древний кейс, поэтому не выношу в ответ.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image

Comment: Похоже на то)) Удалить вопрос?

Comment: @Leonid Не удаляй пожалуйста, это хороший вопрос